# need Wpf equivalent of SystemInformation.DragSize

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

Trying to implement Wpf Listbox dragging, and I need the Wpf equivalent of the SystemInformation.DragSize property.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is SystemParameters namespace.
Specifically, `SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance` 
and `SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance`